# How to implement DarkMode Into app in Swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, ios-darkmode

sorry if that question was asked but couldn't find the right answer across stackOverFlow so I'm asking ..

I'm trying to implement dark mode into my app, but unfortunately it doesn't work well for me while using tableviews, it does changes my background and stuff, but I can't change the color of my groups in my tableview.

Here's an image to illustrate the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWfiu.jpg (can't upload it here cause its too big).

Also Here is my Code:

```
// MARK: - Premium Section - DarkMode + Graph:
    @IBAction func darkModeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let current = sender.isOn ? Theme.dark : Theme.light
        
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *)  {
//            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle(rawValue: current.stateMode)!
            //STEP1: Saving User Defaults Switcher:
            saveSwitchToggleDarkMode(switcherState: sender.isOn)
                //STEP2: Setting UI Colors Of Settings View:
                self.tableView.backgroundColor = current.backgroundColor
                ///Setting up the barTint Color:
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = current.barTintColor
                ///Setting up the title text color:
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:current.textColor]
                ///Changing back color in navigation controller:
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = current.backItemColor
                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and perhaps easier) method to implement dark mode is to use the iOS dark mode feature that you can trigger in settings.If you want to implement this you can create a custom color set by going to your Assets.xcassets and pressing the plus mark on the bottom -> new color set. On the attributes inspector, name your color under name, and under Appearances, select 'Any, Light, Dark' now you will have a place for 3 different colors. Under Light, put the light mode color, on the dark, the dark mode color.

[image: Your settings must look something like this]

Then on the place where you wish to implement this color,you can change the color to your custom color in the storyboard like so :-

[image: TestColor-Storyboard]

or you can change it in code with something like

`myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "TestColor")`

When the user triggers the Dark mode through their control center or settings, the app will also automatically change accordingly. You can test this by going to settings -> Developer -> Dark appearance or by going to Features -> Toggle Appearance or simply press Shift + Command + A

However this method means that you will not have an independent dark mode because it will only be triggered if the device itself is dark-mode enabled.

Comment: @Avi Sabag try this out and tell me if this works for you

Comment: Will do mate :) thanks for the help, trying it out now, btw I don't want to change the button, I want to let the user to change the appearance to dark mode :)

Comment: it kinda worked, I mean it doesn't change the background to black when I switch the switcher

Comment: if you decide to use this you will have to implement a similar thing  in everything you need to change : /  . Also the user can toggle the dark mode through the control center or through settings, not through a switcher. If you do that everything will automatically change to dark mode :).  When testing you have to do that through settings (In Developer) or you can toggle appearance in Features or shift + Command + A

Answer (score 0):

You should change the mode on the window's level to apply changes to all your controls e.g:

```swift
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
   UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

Comment: there's a way to change all my views to dark mode by one switcher?

Comment: @AviSabag Yes, it changes all your app's UI mode.

Comment: but if you select your background color white, it doesn't work. Try to set background color to your views you have issue, replace white color by system background color

Comment: @asilturk Sure it doesn't work for manually set colors but it works for all default colors inside UITableView etc.